# 2 Views side by side with the same height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm using 2 inner Linearlayouts to divide my screen into 2 sections. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

The first inner Layout has a TextView and a Button. The second one has a ImageView and also a Button. Now I want to get the same height for the TextView and ImageView without setting a fix value for layout_height. The left button should also be in line with the right button.

Here is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          tools:context="de.dk.masterfi.ActMain">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Favoriten"/>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="280dp" android:src="@drawable/training"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hauptmenü"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, note the `android:layout_weight="1"` attribute for `TextView` and `ImageView`:

```
<LinearLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      tools:context="de.dk.masterfi.ActMain">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/welcome"/>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button2" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Favoriten"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/training"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hauptmenü"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html):

```
android:layout_height = "0dp"
android:layout_weight = "1.0"
```

Change the weight according to your specs

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml to

```
<LinearLayout       
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      tools:context="de.dk.masterfi.ActMain">

<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="20dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:orientation="vertical">


      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="@drawable/border"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:text="@string/welcome"/>

         <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Favoriten"/>

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_margin="20dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/training"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hauptmenü"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_trail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.nividbharat.educompanion.activities.TrailActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Button1" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/black">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Button2" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how the preview of the layout look like,

[image]